# Convert Image Control to Byte Array Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, arrays

Objective:
-Save asp.net Image Control to a Folder in the Server
using this code

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imgPath), imageData);
```

imageData is suppose to be in byte array.

Now I have been googline a lot on how to convert Asp.net Image Control to byte array and still haven't found any solution to this.
Alot of the examples outside showed how to save from UploadFile Control and not from the Image Control itself.

The only closest thing I've found is this

```
public static Byte[] ImageToByteArray(Image img)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream mstImage = new MemoryStream();
        img.Save(mstImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Byte[] bytImage = mstImage.GetBuffer();
        return bytImage;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

But what is the correct parameter am i supposed to pass? I tried passing Image1.ImageUrl, but it returns an error.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The method expects an `Image`, so pass `Image1`... But the requirements make little sense. In fact, each time you run the above code, the JPEG artifacts will increase, because you needlessly compress an image again which you already read from disk. Where does the file displayed in the Image control come from, and why don't you simply point to that file? Why do you want the entire file in memory as a byte array?

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an existing [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image(v=vs.110).aspx) Control that looks something like this :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Image ID="ExampleImageControl" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/YourImage.jpg" />
</form>
```

You could create a method that would accept your Image control, read the bytes and return them as expected via the [`File.ReadAllBytes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) method that you mentioned earlier :

```
public byte[] ImageControlToByteArray(Image image)
{
        try
        {
            // Attempt to find the Image that the control points to
            // and read all of it's bytes
            return File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(image.ImageUrl));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Uh oh, there was a problem reading the file
            return new byte[0];
        }
}
```

And then you could retrieve the bytes as expected :

```
var imagebytes = ImageControlToByteArray(YourImageControl);
```

Comment: The image control initially has no ImageUrl. Image is appended after capturing from a webcam. In my ButtonClick method, it wont recognize this method ImageControlToByteArray. Highlighting the method will tell me to generate method stub.

Comment: If the actual image data is posted (e.g. so that you can access it via your server-side code), then you would just need to ensure that you don't call this until after your image is populated. Otherwise, it sounds like you would be using some Javascript-based library to populate your Image (from your webcam), then that's likely an entirely different problem.

Comment: Yeah, the image will be populated after capturing from the webcam.This part has no problem. Now that the image is populated, i want to save it to a folder in the server. Using this line of code File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imgPath), imageData);

Comment: If you already have the data (presumably using `imageData`) and you supply your target path `imgPath`, then that should take care of saving that content to your file as expected assuming no permission issues arise.

Comment: I have found a solution but the image cant be viewed because it says corrupted. int a = Image1.Page.Request.InputStream.ReadByte(); Then I proceed with converting the int to bytes. After that pass the byte array to this File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imgPath), imageData); Successfully saved the picture in the server. But the size of the image is only 1KB.

Comment: You might consider taking a look at your `imageData` within the debugger to ensure that it is actually being read properly (and that the URL when reading it is where you would expected). As if an exception was thrown in the `ImageControlToByteArray()` method, it'll return an empty `byte[]` and might explain your 1KB issue. You'll also likely want to ensure that the extension that you are saving the image using matches the original one as well.

Comment: Problem Solved. ImageData that is being converted to bytes is not the correct value. After capturing image from the webcam, I stored the value of the image.src to a hiddenfield. Then, retrieved the value inside the hiddenfield to be converted to byte array. Passed the byte array value to this File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imgPath), imageData); And it works. Should I post my solution?